# Get variables parsed from Flask URL

Tags: flask

Suppose I have a simple route with a variable part:

```
@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def show_post(post_id):
    return 'Post %d' % post_id
```

Now I want to register a context processor that

1. Only runs when the view function is called with `post_id` as a parameter
2. somehow has access to `post_id`, without having to re-parse the URL all over again with e.g. `re.match`

essentially:

```
@app.context_processor
def foo():
    post_id = ???
    return {'bar': some_function(post_id)}
```

If I could access the `**kwargs` passed to `show_post` in this example *from* the context processor I could do it, but I've found no way to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`request.view_args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.view_args):

```
@app.context_processor
def provide_foo():
    if "post_id" in request.view_args:
        post_id = request.view_args["post_id"]
        return {"bar": some_function(post_id)}
```