# Cloud Functions parsing request path parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to figure out how to parse the URL parameters in GCP cloud functions. I am trying to do pretty much what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921903/get-variables-parsed-from-flask-url) does. Since the entry point to a [HTTP GCP cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) takes a request AFAIK. I can's figure out a way to have Flask parse the URL parameters like in the example I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL parameters isn't very clear. If you talk about query parameter (the params after the ? in the url), you can simply take the [getting started example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python)

```
def hello_world(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()

    # Here the query parameters
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')

    # Here it's in the post body in JSON
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']

    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

If you talk about path parameter, you can rely on the view_args value

```
# Function code
def entrypoint(request):
    return request.view_args, 200

# Test like that
> curl https://us-central1-<PROJECT ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION NAME>/test/to/path
> {"path":"test/to/path"}
```

However, the path parameter isn't split for you, and you need to handle it manually.

---

**EDIT 1**

I found how to hack Flask and use its URL processor. Here my working code sample

```
# Function code
from flask import Flask

def entrypoint(request):
    path = request.view_args['path']
    f = Flask("internal")
    f.add_url_rule("/test/<string:id>", "entrypoint_internal")
    r = f.test_request_context(path=path)
    r.push()
    path_value = r.request.view_args
    r.pop()
    return path_value, 200



# Test like that
> curl https://us-central1-<PROJECT ID>.cloudfunctions.net/<FUNCTION NAME>/test/path
> {"id":"path"}
```

Comment: And a new article inspired by you :) Thanks -> https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-multiple-paths-in-cloud-functions-python-and-flask-fc6780e560d3